# SQL Group By statement within subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery

I am trying to write a query that will return the number of "proactive call cases" made by each employee per month as well as the total number of all cases. Essentially, I am looking to return 3 columns; an EmployeeName, a count of the Proactive Calls for that month, and a count of the total calls that month.  To try and accomplish this I used a subquery.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Select OpenedByName AS EmployeeName, Count(OpenedByName) As NumberOfProactiveCallsMONTH,
  (Select Count(OpenedByName)
   From table1
   Where OpenDate Between '2/1/2014' and '3/1/2014' Group By OpenedByName) AS
   TotalTicketsMONTH
From table1
Where OpenDate Between '2/1/2014' and '3/1/2014' AND ProblemType = 17 
Group By OpenedByName
```

After running the query I got the error saying that:

```
"Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SalesMTDSubQuery, Line 7 Subquery returned
more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."
```

I think it returned this error due to the GroupBy statement that I added in the subquery. When I remove the GroupBy it will just return the same value for every employee. I'm fairly new to using SQL so I'm not really sure of a good way around this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of the subquery? If you group by OpenedName and then get a count won't that be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  OpenedByName AS EmployeeName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ProblemType = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfProactiveCallsMONTH,
        COUNT(1) TotalTicketsMONTH
FROM Table1
Where OpenDate Between '2/1/2014' and '3/1/2014' 
GROUP BY OpenedByName
```

The error you received was due to the fact that when using a sub query as a column, it cannot return more than 1 value.

Now the way you had it structured, it would have returned all the `COUNT` values per OpenedByName, instead of a single value per OpenedBy.

If you realy wish to use your quer, you need to limit the lookup in the column select to the actual OpenedByName. So something like

```
Select OpenedByName AS EmployeeName, Count(OpenedByName) As NumberOfProactiveCallsMONTH,
  (Select Count(OpenedByName)
   From table1 t
   Where OpenDate Between '2/1/2014' and '3/1/2014' 
   AND t.OpenedByName = t1.OpenedByName) AS
   TotalTicketsMONTH
From table1 t1
Where OpenDate Between '2/1/2014' and '3/1/2014' AND ProblemType = 17 
Group By OpenedByName
```

Comment: This is the solution I used and it works great.  I just was wondering about one part of the query.  What is the COUNT (1) counting to get the TotalTicketsMONTH? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to relate the sub-select to the outer statement, otherwise, as you noticed, you return multiple lines in the sub-select which doesn't work.

```
SELECT  OpenedByName AS EmployeeName
      , COUNT(OpenedByName) AS NumberOfProactiveCallsMONTH
      , ( SELECT    COUNT(OpenedByName)
          FROM      table1 b
          WHERE     OpenDate BETWEEN '2/1/2014' AND '3/1/2014'
                AND b.OpenedByName = a.OpenedByName
          GROUP BY  OpenedByName
        ) AS TotalTicketsMONTH
FROM    table1 a
WHERE   OpenDate BETWEEN '2/1/2014' AND '3/1/2014'
        AND ProblemType = 17
GROUP BY OpenedByName
```

But you can greatly simplify this by using a conditional sum instead of a sub-select:

```
SELECT  OpenedByName AS EmployeeName
      , SUM(ProblemType = 17) NumberOfProactiveCallsMONTH
      , COUNT(OpenedByName) AS TotalTicketsMONTH
FROM    table1
WHERE   OpenDate BETWEEN '2/1/2014' AND '3/1/2014'
GROUP BY OpenedByName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
Select a.OpenedByName AS EmployeeName, Count(a.OpenedByName) As NumberOfProactiveCallsMONTH,
b.TotalTicketsMONTH  AS   TotalTicketsMONTH
From table1 a
INNER JOIN   
  (Select OpenedByName ,Count(OpenedByName) AS TotalTicketsMONTH   From table1
  Where OpenDate Between '2/1/2014' and '3/1/2014' Group By OpenedByName) b ON
  a.OpenedByName =  b.OpenedByName
Where a.OpenDate Between '2/1/2014' and '3/1/2014' AND a.ProblemType = 17 
Group By a.OpenedByName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a relation from the inner query to the outer query:

```
SELECT  t1.OpenedByName AS EmployeeName, 
        COUNT(t1.OpenedByName) As NumberOfProactiveCallsMONTH,
        (   SELECT  COUNT(OpenedByName)
            FROM    table1 t2
            WHERE   t2.OpenDate BETWEEN '2/1/2014' AND '3/1/2014'
            AND     t1.OpenedByName = t2.OpenedByName
        ) AS TotalTicketsMONTH
FROM    table1 t1
WHERE   t1.OpenDate BETWEEN '2/1/2014' AND '3/1/2014' 
AND     t1.ProblemType = 17 
GROUP BY t1.OpenedByName;
```

However you can simplify the query by using a conditional aggregate (i.e. only counting when additional criteria is met):

```
SELECT  t1.OpenedByName AS EmployeeName,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.ProblemType = 17 THEN t1.OpenedByName END) As NumberOfProactiveCallsMONTH,
        COUNT(t1.OpenedByName) As TotalTicketsMONTH
FROM    table1 t1
WHERE   t1.OpenDate BETWEEN '2/1/2014' AND '3/1/2014' 
GROUP BY t1.OpenedByName;
```

The next improvement would be to change your date format to one that not culture specific - is `2/1/2014` 2nd January or 1st February? If you use `yyyyMMdd` there is no ambiguity.

Finally, your query will include tickets opened on 1st March at midnight, I suspect these should not be included in February's data, you would be better of using `>=` and `<'. Making your final query:

```
SELECT  t1.OpenedByName AS EmployeeName,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.ProblemType = 17 THEN t1.OpenedByName END) As NumberOfProactiveCallsMONTH,
        COUNT(t1.OpenedByName) As TotalTicketsMONTH
FROM    table1 t1
WHERE   t1.OpenDate >= '20140201' 
AND     t1.OpenDate < '2014031' 
GROUP BY t1.OpenedByName;
```

For further reading on Date range queries:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date - range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)